# Expect: get back from SSH

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, expect

I am trying to write an expect script that:

1, Logs in to my raspberry pi via SSH

2, Does something in the raspberry pi

3, sends "exit\r" to get back to my computer

4, Does something on my computer

My current sollution looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1

spawn ssh pi@XXXXXXXX
expect "*: "
send "raspberry\r"

expect "pi@"
# Do something here
send "exit\r"

expect "username@"
send "pwd" # pwd just as a test

expect eof
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "pwd""
```

I have tried googling, but can't find anything that solves this question.

I would be really thankful if someone could help me!

Comment: why do you want to `send pwd` after `send exit\r`? you cannot interact with the spawned process after it exits.

Comment: No, I want to send pwd to my computer after I have exited.

Comment: Expect uses [tag:tcl]. You can use [exec](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.html) to run commands on local system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're spawning the ssh program. When you exit from the remote session, ssh ends, and now you don't have a running process to interact with.

Expect has another mechanism to invoke external programs: there's `spawn` but also `exec`. This does not provide any interactivity: the `exec`'ed program just runs and exits (and returns its output).

So, it depends on what "something" you want to do:

- spawn bash on your local machine to then use with send & expect
- exec something.

In addition to the `expect(1)` man page, since Expect is a Tcl extension, there are also [the Tcl commands](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm) to use.